# setuptools see a subdir in my package

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I have created a `setup.py` for my package based on `setuptools`. It worked very well until I added a submodule that is actually a subdirectory with an `__init__.py` inside. Now the installation completes normally, but when I try to import the package I get

```
ImportError: No module named genalgs
```

My package is organized as follows:

```
topdir/
-> setup.py
-> packg/
---> __init__.py
---> submodule.py (which imports genalgs)
---> opthermod.py
---> genalgs/
-----> __init__.py
-----> subsubmod.py
-----> othersub.py
```

I have checked the dir `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/packg/` and everything is in there except the `genalgs/` directory, so I'm guessing this is the error.

The `setup` call I'm using is

```
setup(name='pckg',
      version='0.1.0',
      description='something',
      long_description=open('README.md').read(),
      url='https://github.com/som/som.git',
      author='My name',
      author_email='mymail@mail.com',
      license='GNU GPL V3.0',
      packages=['pckg'],
      install_requires=depencies)
```

Comment: which code are you trying to do import?

Comment: @nikniknik2016 I don't quite get the question. I'm running `setup.py`, which installs the package "successfully", and then I'm trying to import the package from any random location in ipython with `import packg`, which gives me that error when I get to a `import genalgs` line.

Comment: may be `import packg.genalgs` will helps ?

Comment: Nope: `ImportError: No module named genalgs`. The problem in that `genalgs` isn't included in the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `packages` parameter to your `setup()` call more clever to tell it about all the packages you want included:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(...
     packages=find_packages(),
...)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. On a side-note, is there something like this for `distutils`?